# Codeigniter:SOAP, Custom Library not returning Exception

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap

I am creating an API using SOAP in codeigniter, So for ease i created a custom library to n number of methods 
So here is my code

**Controller:**

```
$input=array(
                "bat" => "xsd:string", 
            );
            $name="cricket";
            $doc="cricket";
            $this->register($name, $input, $doc);
$this->server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));

public function register($name, $input, $doc){

                 $data=$this->server->register("master.".$name,  
                 $input, 
                 array('result' => 'xsd:string'),
                "urn:StemiSoap", 
                "urn:".base_url()."".$name, 
                "rpc",
                "encoded", 
                $doc
                );

             return $data;
        }
```

and here is my custom library where i created a n number of methods

```
class Master{
   public function cricket($bat) 
   {
    try {
        $a=$bat/0;
        return  $a;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e
    }
   }

}
```

and Here is my client code where i am calling the method via SOAP

```
$result = $this->client->call("master.cricket", 
    array(
        "bat" => "10", 
        )
    );
 echo  $result;
```

But the try catch not throwing any exception just a blank page is receiving, even if i initialize the array with more than 10 values if i left even a single data it is difficult to find where the exception is occurred, it is not even returning anything after that error

Comment: The code above `register()` in your controller, where is it suppose to be ? in your `index()` ? Try `return $this->register($name, $input, $doc);`

Comment: yaaa the register will be index sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: AdrienXL return in register just gives blank page not in client but in server

Comment: That's normal as you never output anything. You should echo something to actually see something.

Comment: normally the functions works better, it returning when i pass the value from client, but if there is any error happens , the code is stop executing on the line which it gets error || Example: try {
        return "got" $b=10/0;
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
      }

returning the text "GOT in client"